# Is it possible to have a subfolder exempt from review requirements in TFS Branch Policies?

Tags: tfs

We have a TFS Branch Policy in place to require review of files committed to the Repo. Currently this covers the entire repository.

I want to add a subfolder to the repo that is exempt from the review process. So that everything **except** files checked into this subfolder require review.

So currently our Branch policy looks like: [image: Review Policy]

I would like the "Documentation" folder to be exempt from review.
I understand I could force reviews on on folders except that one, but I was hoping I could avoid setting up policy for each folder except the Documentation one.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No such option. Check Q&A on this website: https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/git/branch-policies#how_works

**Q: What type of wildcard characters are supported when configuring required code reviewers?**

Single asterisks (*) are supported, and will match any number of characters, including both forward-slashes (/) and back-slashes (). Question marks (?) will match any single character.

Examples:

```
*.sql will match all files with the .sql extension
/ConsoleApplication/* will match all files under the folder named ConsoleApplication
/.gitattributes will match the .gitattributes file in the root of the repo
*/.gitignore will match any .gitignore file in the repo
```